# Issue with sending variables to AJAX ( php forms)

Tags: php, ajax, forms

Greetings fellow programmers, I've been trying to solve this all day but I dont know much with ajax. I can handle regular forms that require refresh.

Basically I have a form where the client enters their desired quantity and a button that says add to cart with an ajax function that handles the post request.

```
               <form id="qnt'.$ID'">
           <input type="hidden" value="'.$price.'" name="price">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Quantity in Kilo" name="qty" required>
           <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick= add('.$ID.') class="filled-button" class="add2cart">Add To Cart</button></h6>
           </form>
```

This is the ajax request:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
     function add(id){
       qnt = $('#qnt'+id).serialize();
       $('#qnt'+id).trigger("reset");
       $.ajax({
         url:'add2cart.php',
         method:'POST',
         data:{
         'id': id,
         'qnt': qnt

         },
         success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
         }
       });
     }
  </script>
```

Now this works completely fine(Tbh a friend helped me do it) , Now I reached a situation where I want to add another variable to the form:

```
               <form id="qnt'.$ID'">
           <input type="hidden" value="'.$newPrice.'" name="newPrice">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Quantity in Kilo" name="qty" required>
           <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick= add('.$ID.') class="filled-button" class="add2cart">Add To Cart</button></h6>
           </form>
```

How can I pass that new hidden input with the ajax script? Thanks.

Comment: Add a new parameter to the `data` argument within the ajax function - that said you would be unwise to do so as anything entered into the browser can be easily modified.

Comment: I have tried to add a new one ( with 100% correct syntax) but it caused the button to stop working
newPrice : price

Comment: You don't really need to send the price in the ajax function - only the product ID and quantity. The PHP script will do a database lookup to find the price ( and that way the price is what you have set not what someone may have changed it to ) - the details can then be stored in the `cart`

Comment: I made an intellegent sale system which analyzes user statics and gives them sales according to whats available, when there is a sale to certain client I want the ajax to pass the new price with the add to cart and not to lookup the database for the original price, that way I wouldn't get the price after sale.

Comment: What other variable do you wish to add to the form and where does this variable come from? Is it user-input?

Comment: Once I am showing the info of the products there is their regular price that comes from database, now if a sale exists for that said user, I made a variable called newPrice where I calculated the original price and the sale% , now when the user adds to cart, I want the new price to be added into their cart and not the original price from the database.
Which means I want to do newPrice * quantity and not databasePrice * quantity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236834/discussion-between-professor-abronsius-and-ameen-assadi).

Answer (score 1):

You can place the id in a hidden input in the form, then the serialize will have the id in  it

```
   <form id="qnt'.$ID'">
       <input type="hidden" value="'.$ID.'" name="id">
       <input type="hidden" value="'.$newPrice.'" name="newPrice">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Quantity in Kilo" name="qty" required>
       <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick= add('.$ID.') class="filled-button" class="add2cart">Add To Cart</button></h6>
   </form>


 function add(id){
   qnt = $('#qnt'+id).serialize();
   $('#qnt'+id).trigger("reset");
   $.ajax({
     url:'add2cart.php',
     method:'POST',
     data: qnt,
     success:function(data){
       console.log(data);
     }
   });
 }
```

Comment: I dont think you understood what I want, This has nothing to do with "ID" this is just about the newPrice.